# Como listar el primer registro por grupo en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench, mysqldb

Tengo una consulta que me trae el estado de la asistencia del alumno por cada asistencia tomada en la clase. (No se si me deje entender ,les dejo un ejemplo):

```
SELECT 
aac.codAlumno,CONCAT(a.apePaterno,' ',a.apeMaterno,', ',a.nombres) as nombres, aac.estado, aac.codClase
FROM asistencia_alumno_clase aac 
INNER JOIN clases c ON aac.codClase = c.id 
INNER JOIN oeraae_estandar.alumnos a ON aac.codAlumno = a.codAlumno_fk  
WHERE c.periodo = '20201' 
AND c.codHorario = '19464' 
AND aac.codAlumno != '08115218'
ORDER BY nombres asc, c.id asc, aac.estado desc;
```

En la clase 1 se tomo 3 asistencias
En la clase 7 se tomo 3 asistencias
En la clase 10 se tomo 2 asistencias

```
 codigo       Nombre               estado   codClase
35482522I   CASAS ZAPATA, CARLOS      1         1
35482522I   CASAS ZAPATA, CARLOS      0         1
35482522I   CASAS ZAPATA, CARLOS      0         1
35482522I   CASAS ZAPATA, CARLOS      0         7
35482522I   CASAS ZAPATA, CARLOS      0         7
35482522I   CASAS ZAPATA, CARLOS      0         7
35482522I   CASAS ZAPATA, CARLOS      1         10
35482522I   CASAS ZAPATA, CARLOS      0         10
```

Pero lo que necesito que me liste es esto (El primer resultado por clase)

```
 codigo       Nombre               estado   codClase
35482522I   CASAS ZAPATA, CARLOS      1         1
35482522I   CASAS ZAPATA, CARLOS      0         7
35482522I   CASAS ZAPATA, CARLOS      1         10
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de mySQL utilizas?

Comment: Versión -> 8.0.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que utilizas mySQL 8 o superior, puedes valerte de

- *CTE* para hacer la consulta legible
- [Funciones de ventana](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html), por ejemplo [`rank()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank) o [`row_number()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) para particionar y *numerar* las filas del resultado y finalmente quedarte solamente con la primera fila de cada partición.

Por ejemplo:

```
with 
Base as (
SELECT   aac.codAlumno
       , CONCAT(a.apePaterno,' ',a.apeMaterno,', ',a.nombres) as nombres
       , aac.estado
       , aac.codClase
       , row_number() over (partition by aac.codAlumno, aac.codClase order by aae.estado desc) NumeroFilaAlumno
  FROM asistencia_alumno_clase aac 
       INNER JOIN clases c ON aac.codClase = c.id 
       INNER JOIN oeraae_estandar.alumnos a ON aac.codAlumno = a.codAlumno_fk  
 WHERE c.periodo = '20201' 
   AND c.codHorario = '19464' 
   AND aac.codAlumno != '08115218'
ORDER BY nombres asc, c.id asc, aac.estado desc
)
select   CodAlumno
       , nombres
       , estado
       , codClase
  from Base
 where NumeroFilaAlumno = 1
 order by Nombres, CodClase
```

Comment: Munchas gracias !! me salvaste, estaré leyendo sobre esto para entenderlo por completo

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda, justamente la idea es que lo entiendas antes de utilizarlo, por eso mismo está allí la referencia a la documentación, además del ejemplo de cómo se utiliza, con el cual debieras jugar un poco.