# Tomar primer registro el primero por fecha de cada usuario

Tags: mysql, sql

Lo que quiero es sacar datos de acuerdo a la primera vez que el un usuario realizo una operación ya que como son muchos usuarios estan en desorden, el usuario tiene varios datos en diferentes fechas y hasta de la misma fecha por ejemplo:

```
 id Usuario           fecha             monto
   565465       2021-05-19 11:04:10    $ 5,154
   565465       2021-03-09 14:04:06    $ 5,686
   565465       2021-05-24 11:25:07    $ 881,510
   565465       2020-02-05 23:01:25    $ 355,118
   132456       2020-02-29 23:01:53    $ 86,186
   132456       2021-11-05 22:22:09    $ 260
   132456       2020-01-17 23:01:10    $ 684,055
   132456       2021-04-25 23:01:10    $ 684,055
```

De acuerdo a estos datos tengo que sacar su primera operacion lo que debería quedar es así:

```
 id Usuario           fecha             monto
   565465       2020-02-05 23:01:25    $ 355,118
   132456       2020-01-17 23:01:10    $ 684,055
```

Comment: Y que intentaste?

Comment: ¿no has probado usar el buscador del sitio? esto se ha preguntado en repetidas ocasiones

Comment: Por ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/386389/como-listar-el-primer-registro-por-grupo-en-mysql

Comment: Excelente si me funciono gracias